# how to display file download dialog for PDF in jax-rs?

Tags: java, rest, pdf, download, jax-rs

I'm creating REST app and PDF using `Jasper Report` and would like to display file download  dialog for PDF on browser.

This is exactly what I am looking for:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/download-pdf-file-from-jax-rs/

My code below creates PDF file (MyAwesomeJasperReport25.pdf) but file download dialog does not show up on the browser and I don't understand why.

```
@GET
@Path("pdf")
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response outputPDF() {

    OutputStream output = null;

    try {    
        File jrxmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\m-takayashiki\\report2.jrxml");

        if(jrxmlFile.exists()) {

            //jrxml compile
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxmlFile.getAbsolutePath());

            //some code emitted        

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);

            String filePath = "C:\\Users\\m-takayashiki\\MyAwesomeJasperReport25.pdf";
            output = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath)); 
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output); 


            // From here trying to ask user to download PDF        

            ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) filePath);

            response.header("Content-disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=MyAwesomeJasperReportDownload.pdf");

            return response.build();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("-------------------- PDF exception ");
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(output != null) { output.close(); }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check two things:

1. Shouldn't you put instance of File instead of filePath in response entity ("Response.ok((Object) filePath)")?
2. Does your JAX-RS implementation have entity provider for File class?

Comment: You are correct. I should have file instance not file path. Thanks! Second question, I'm going to check..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the file byte[] in the entity because Jersey does not have a MessageBodyWriter for File. You could use FileUtils from **Apache Commons IO** to convert File to byte[]. Finally your code looks like this:

```
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
```

Answer (score -2):

You forget to put the output object in `Ok()` method:

`ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) filePath);`

**Correct:**

`ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((output) filePath);`

Comment: Are u sure? "output" is instance and cannot be used to cast againt the variable "filepath". Does it even compile?